# Increase in the size of nested parenthesis with \left and \right

Tags: math-mode

I want to obtain an increase in the size of nested parenthesis with a single command like `\left` and `\right`, something like the right term of
[image]

but using the code used for the left term.

(The image is created using `\left(1 + \left(f(x),g(x)\right)\right)` and `\Big(1 + \big(f(x),g(x)\big)\Big)`)

I could simply use `\bib`, `\Big`, ... but I don't want to keep track of the content all the time.

I have no clue how to define a new set of `\left` and `\right` for this purpose.

Comment: I believe that there is no need at all to increase the size; maybe you can use `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` for the outer parentheses. Size `\Big` is definitely excessive.

Comment: @egreg I have some commands with `\left` and `\right`, I can't use `\bigl` and `\bigr` if the content has a `\frac` for example, I want to respect that but always getting a but larger parenthesis that the one the normal `\left` would give.

Comment: @oliversm It does, adding this `\delimiterfactor=1001` is enough to obtain my desired effect, I will play with the other quantities to see what else do I get. Thanks!